# How to customize the very first page of the manual?

Tags: doxygen

By default, the first page that doxygen generates, in Rich Text Format (RTF) with below states:

```
TITLE

AUTHOR
Version
CREATEDATE
```

I want to customize this. I've tried the following, but it customizes the section *after* the index, rather than the very first page of the document:

```
/*!
 * @mainpage My Project
 * @version 0.91
 * @author Jack Vance, 2010.
 * CreateDate 2010-06-26
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> For RTF output, you can generate the default style sheet file (see RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE) using:
>
> ```
> doxygen -w rtf rtfstyle.cfg
> ```

You should then be able to edit the stylesheet to change the output the way you want.

Comment: Thats good enough for me: apparently its *impossible* to alter the front page of the Rich Text Format (RTF) output, without altering the style sheet.

Answer (score 8):

No need to modify the template. After generating the rtf, in MS Word, select all->right click->Update Fields

Comment: but the AUTHOR field for rtf  is in the extension file (RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE)

Answer (score 1):

in Doxygen 1.18.11, creating the style sheet didn't allow me to specify the author.  For that, I had to create and modify the "extensions file" via:

doxygen -e rtf extensionsFile